# HTML/Javascript function help for a newbie

Tags: javascript, html

So, I am writing a piece of code which checks the month of a number after it has been entered into a textbox, it checks to see if it is a valid number of a month (1-12) and if it is not displays an error message. I get the basic principle of it but i dont get how to run the checking after pressing the button, if you want to help that would be great ! And try and base it om what i already have :p

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jA35X.jpg

Comment: If you want someone to do something with your code, post it as code not as a screenshot of code.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function myFunction(){

number = document.getElementById('myText').value;
  if(isNaN(number)){
     alert('Not a valid month');
  }else { 
      if( number > 0 && number <= 12){
         alert('valid month');
      }else{
         alert('Not a valid month');
      }
  }
}
```

```html
Month no: <input type="text" id="myText" />
<button onclick="myFunction();">Go</button>
```

Comment: if I enter XXX in input box it returns "Valid number"

Answer (score 0):

The original, more complete way is:

```
function myFunction() {
  var month = parseInt(document.getElementById('myText').value);
  if (typeof month === 'number' && month <= 12 && month > 0) {
    alert('yes! valid month! ');
  } else {
    alert('invalid month! ');
  }
}
```

`document.getElementById('myText').value` should be a string, and `parseInt()` convert it to a number.

**Update:** Use the complete solution, or may cause lots of problems.

<del>However, If you don't want to make it too complicate, just use below code.</del>

```js
function myFunction() {
  var month = document.getElementById('myText').value;
  if (month <= 12 && month > 0) {
    alert('yes! valid month! ');
  } else {
    alert('invalid month! ');
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <title>Month Checker 3000</title>

  <h1>Month Checker</h1>
  Month Number:
  <input type="text" id="myText" />
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Go</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @hopkins-matt Yea.. Don't wanna make it hard for Max.

Comment: Doesn' validate if it's number or not

Comment: @ZlatkoVujicic Sorry, I validated it for the first time, and then I deleted it to simplify the code, and I updated the answer to add it back.

Comment: This will not work if month is 12, which is a valid month

Comment: @Keerthi Oops. Fix it. Thx.